# Just Upgraded to 11.04 form 10.10. It hangs after boot and just new desktop is shown

Tags: 11.04, unity, upgrade, launcher

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 11.04 from 10.10 using direct Internet connection and now just new looking desktop (with the Launcher on the left) is shown and **system hangs**. Mouse cursor is moving but clicking icons and keyboard shortcuts have no effect.
Maybe something went wrong during upgrade procedure. you know, **It did not finished correctly**; **at the last seconds** of installing upgrades it gave an error saying "it can not acquire lock" and exited. I just manually clicked "restart to complete upgrade" from the menu.
**I run the upgrade routine again but it says the system is upgraded.**

No shortcut key works, (I hit win key or Alt+F2 but the result is nothing). Yes, Caps lock is working. I mean that when I press it the Caps Lock light turns on).
**I am sure that there is no special process that makes CPU busy**, mouse cursor is moving so fast and my CPU fans are in normal mode and does not make loud noise.
I boot in Recovery mode and typed the upgrade command and as I said it says that the system is already upgraded.
**You know, the situation is very similar to a state that you have a window in front and clicking items in the background has no result.**
I haven`t installed Ubuntu from wubi.

Comment: Is your ubuntu installed with wubi?????

Comment: No, It is a seprate OS and appears in Grub.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was because of the unity desktop (it is the default view in Natty). **I just selected Ubuntu Classic as the default session** from System Settings -> Login Screen Settings and now the old desktop is OK.
Tnx

Comment: Good you found your way out!

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to bring up the dash using the super key (windows key)? or using Alt +F2?
Are the Caps Lock and Num Lock keys working? If it is very slow in showing up, then i guess some process is slowing down everything in your system . The main culprit would be compiz or X.org. 
Try checking your system's processes by typing `top` in a terminal window.
This will show you what application is using the most cpu. If you see its comiz using the most memory, try typing  `compiz --replace &` in a terminal window

You may also try to run an upgrade command.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

See if that helps.